# Error: Specified EntryPointExe 'MyApp.UWP.exe' was not found in the project outputs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I have a packaging project that has a UWP app as one of its applications.

It used to work well but now when I try to build the packager I get the error in the title. But the file *does* exist in the UWP project's obj/x86/release folder.

So what might be the problem?

**EDIT**

This happens only in Release, not in Debug.

Comment: Hi, We found a [similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/871255/packaging-project-microsoftdesktopbridgetargets591.html), which seems to be the same as the one you encountered, you can try to upgrade Visual Studio to the specified version (16.5 preview 2 release), this should fix the problem.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Thanks. Do you know around when is it supposed to come out of preview into general release?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this. You can stay focused on [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview)

Comment: Same here with VS 2022, newest version. Did you find another solution than  upgrading to a newer version?